# Reach external values?

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring

spriteManager is an instance of an external class I have,  To access PlayerHelath and selectedFrameOffset   I repeteadly have to start with:  spriteManager.  many times.

```
    if (spriteManager.PlayerHealth == 3)
        spriteManager.selectedFrameOffset = 0;
    else if (spriteManager.PlayerHealth == 2)
        spriteManager.selectedFrameOffset = 30;
    else if (spriteManager.PlayerHealth == 1)
        spriteManager.selectedFrameOffset = 60;
    else if (spriteManager.PlayerHealth == 0)
        spriteManager.selectedFrameOffset = 90;
```

Is there a chance I can reference the use of  spriteManager.   only 1 time and end up with this:  code,   to gain more readability ?

```
    if (PlayerHealth == 3)
        selectedFrameOffset = 0;
    else if (PlayerHealth == 2)
        selectedFrameOffset = 30;
    else if (PlayerHealth == 1)
        selectedFrameOffset = 60;
    else if (PlayerHealth == 0)
        selectedFrameOffset = 90;
```

Comment: Please specify why this user has been given a downvote. The user is obviously new. Please educate the newcomers instead of pouncing on the downvote.

Comment: What should happen if `PlayerHealth` is not in [3,2,1,0] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
spriteManager.selectedFrameOffset = GetFrameOffset(spriteManager.PlayerHealth);

private int GetFrameOffset(int playerHealth)
{
    return (3 - playerHealth) * 30;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch of hidden logic

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy sorry for reusing your code:), but your "switch" solution seems more proper as my method can return minus values.

Comment: That's OK) I already referenced your great catch in my solution, and of course upvoted you :)

Answer (score 7):

```
spriteManager.selectedFrameOffset = GetFrameOffset(spriteManager.PlayerHealth);
```

Where getting offset is simple switch

```
private int GetFrameOffset(int playerHealth)
{
    switch(playerHealth)
    {
       case 3: return 0;
       case 2: return 30;
       case 1: return 60;
       // etc
       default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Consider also moving this logic into `SpriteManager` class. E.g. you can make `selectedFrameOffset` property calculated based on current health value:

```
public int selectedFrameOffset
{
    get
    {
        switch(PlayerHealth)
        {
           case 3: return 0;
           case 2: return 30;
           case 1: return 60;
           // etc
           default:
                throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

---

As @daryal noticed hidden logic in your if..else block, I'd go with following solution in `SpriteManager` class:

```
private const int frameOffset = 30;

public int SelectedFrameOffset
{
    get 
    { 
        if (PlayerHealth <= 3)
           return (3 - PlayerHealth) * frameOffset; 

        return defaultValue; // or throw
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, your latest edit (with the arithmetics) produces negative results for playerhealth < 3...

Comment: @elgonzo agree. And it's hard to tell what should happen if value of health is not 0, 1, 2, or 3. Maybe some default value is used.. Or it is simply not possibly to be other value. Anyway, added check

Comment: hehe, you need some coffee, i think :))) Just turn the subtraction around as in @daryal's answer. `3-playerHealth` instead of `playerHealth-3` -- that would yield the same result as in the OP's example code... (but that would not cover values outside [0,1,2,3] of course)

Comment: @elgonzo yeah, something with energy inside would be great)

Comment: health value of 0 or negative Triggs gameOver, so it should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.net you could do something like this:

```
Dim theCustomer As New Customer

theCutomer.Name = "Paul"
theCutomer.City = "New York" 

// or alternativly:

With theCustomer
    .Name = "Paul"
    .City = "New York" 
End With
```

But there is no way to do it in C#.
In C# you could use a shorter variable name:

```
SpriteManager sp = new SpriteManager();
sp.selectedFrameOffset = 90;
```

or optimize your code with `switch`-statemets etc. like shown from Sergey.